# Have Wordpress Use a Different Database for users

Tags: database, mysql, table

I have imported my users from Filemaker into a different table in Mysql. Can I have my user login to that database instead of the wp_users table. If so how do I connect it?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: There's not really a good reason to do this.  You'd override many of the features that WordPress utilizes and cause yourself quite a few other minor issues.  Why not just import the users into the correct database.  There are MANY options/methods of doing so, including several plugins.

Comment: Thank you. I knew there might be some issues. Could you recommend some plugins.